# can i substring a field after i parsed a file with delimiter in linux

Tags: linux, substring

for example

here is the data

```
45|019|6|113|201901101522|40000539306|
45|015|1|6|201901101045|40000707530|
45|018|6|201|201901101733|40002235304|
45|009|8|377|201901101732|40002097431|
```

and i want to see like this

```
2019011
2019011
2019011
2019011
2019011
```

this is what i have already tried  : `cut -d'|' -f5 < input.txt`
these what i get

```
201901101522
201901101045
201901101733
201901101732
```

Comment: Just a thought, but your cut string looks like a date in format YYYYMMDD and you appear to be cutting off the second part of the day with your example... 2019011 should be 20190110 so you’ll need to do cut -c1-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pipe it into `cut` again:

```
cut -d'|' -f5 <input.txt | cut -c1-7
```

Or use `awk`:

```
awk -F'\|' '{print substr($5, 1, 7)}' input.txt
```

Comment: thank you both of them worked, but awk was lil faster

Answer (score 0):

I'm jumping to conclusions, but I assume you want a complete date, not just the "10"s of the day?

```
gawk -F'|' '{print gensub( /^(.{8}).*/, "\\1", "1",$5)}' data 
20190110
20190110
20190110
20190110
```